# Restricting Input to Numbers Only In Textbox? (c#)

Tags: c#, textbox, numbers, limiting

Please excuse me for asking this, I have looked at various different questions relating to this and I still can not get it to implement.

Using the answers I have looked at, I have gathered this, and applied this coding to my text box.

```
private void TxtBox5_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)))
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Now, when I proceed to run the program, I am still able to enter letters into it. I do not know what to do next, so any solution would be great. thanks.

Comment: first: step through the code in debugger and make sure routine is being  called

Comment: If this is a windows form application why dont you use NumericUpDown control which will only allow numbers.

Comment: Is there a special reason that you are using a textbox? The easiest way to restrict the input to numbers is to use numericUpDown instead of textBox. If you really need the textBox you might make create a string or a list containing all digits (and maybe decimal point) and then check if the string that you enter contains any other character

Comment: The MSDN documenation for [Control.KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) has an example for it.

Comment: @Coder, I'm using a textbox because it looks cleaner than the NumericUpDown.

Comment: @Fadzitt have you used a debugger to see if that method is actually called like Mitch Wheat asked?

Comment: @Dirk I do not know how to do that, otherwise I would do it.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @Fadzitt Please take a look at this small [debugging tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging) then.

Comment: @ShaktiPrakashSingh Windows form,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay this is what i made just now, it works 100% just tested it.Note that my textBox is named serialTxtBox, you can change it to yours.

```
void serialTxtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool enteredLetter = false;
            Queue<char> text = new Queue<char>();
            foreach (var ch in this.serialTxtBox.Text)
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(ch))
                {
                    text.Enqueue(ch);
                }
                else
                {
                    enteredLetter = true;
                }
            }

            if (enteredLetter)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while (text.Count > 0)
                {
                    sb.Append(text.Dequeue());
                }                

                this.serialTxtBox.Text = sb.ToString();
                this.serialTxtBox.SelectionStart = this.serialTxtBox.Text.Length;
            }
        }
```

EDIT: Definitely you are doing something wrong. In your form constructor which is named like your form. In my case SerialGenerator, you need to initialize the event. In my case :

```
public SerialGenerator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.serialTxtBox.TextChanged += serialTxtBox_TextChanged;
        }
```

this will fire the method everytime someone enters something in your textBox. Make sure you rename it to your textbox's name

Comment: I can still enter letters, I'm doing something wrong. would it be possible for you to help over teamviewer or similar?

Comment: and we have it working, I honestly can't thank you enough. Sorry for not being the most helpful of people, but we all do start somewhere.

Comment: I have to have 15 rep to upvote it, but believe me I tried to as soon as it worked.

Comment: if to write on the beginning **var textBox = (TextBox) sender;** then it does not matter what name textbox has.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
private void TxtBox5_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)))
        { e.Handled = true; }
}
```

I don't think this is the best one, but you may make this work by tweaking a little, I guess. I don't have VS right now to check what would work.

EDIT: My bad. I think you can use the above one not on keypress but on textchanged event of the textbox. It's more like a tweak than a solution. Just to make you progress if you are stuck and don't get a better solution.

Update: Updated the code. Please check if this one helps you.

Comment: that gives off errors, has some "invalid arguements"

Comment: still no result when debugging.

Comment: I checked it out on my system and seemed to work properly. Can you try and create a new Win Forms project with a single text box in the form and test this. I think there might be something else that is causing the issue.

Comment: Started a new project, added the textbox, added the code and I can still enter numbers. this is really odd now.

Comment: But you wanted to enter numbers only, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,hope this works

```
   private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        int asciiCode = Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar);
        if ((asciiCode >= 48 && asciiCode <= 57))
        {


        }
        else
       {                MessageBox.Show("Not allowed!");
            e.Handled = true;


        }
    }
```

Comment: no luck there, didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I have added events on code level, since there can be a possibility in your code not correctly event added to the control.

Note : **The KeyPress event is not raised by noncharacter keys**
you need to use both `KeyDown` and `KeyPress` events

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool nonNumberEntered = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.KeyDown+=new KeyEventHandler(textBox1_KeyDown);
        textBox1.KeyPress+=new KeyPressEventHandler(textBox1_KeyPress);
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (nonNumberEntered == true)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        nonNumberEntered = false;

        if (e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.D9)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad9)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
                {
                    nonNumberEntered = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
        {
            nonNumberEntered = true;
        }
    }
}
```

REF : [Control.KeyPress Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx)

Comment: how do I reference the control.keypress?

Comment: `textBox1.KeyPress+= give the event`, or you can do this from control -> properties -> events in designer view

Comment: I am now receiving an error with "nonNumberEntered" not existing in the current context.

Comment: you need to add `nonNumberEntered` flag as in the sample code

Comment: How would I do that? I've had a look and I can't work it out (sorry for bad questions, really just starting off)

Comment: @Fadzitt Download [this code sample](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-y6DAoC4jwvVHBSSVJURS1oTlE/edit?usp=sharing) and check the code and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
private void TxtBox5_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {         
        int num = 0;
         e.Handled = !int.TryParse(e.KeyChar.ToString(), out num);

    }
```

Comment: no luck, chucks a lot of errors.

Comment: @Fadzitt : it's changed ..

Comment: still able to enter letters, starting to think I'm not including something on myside. Should I be adding anything in public Form1()